# Amazon IAP works in sandbox mode, but not in real life

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to enable Amazon IAP for a Unity game. Currently Unity plugin is only available for Amazon IAP v1.0. The game uses Prime31 for Android and iOS stores, I'm implementing the Amazon IAP side-by-side with that.
The purchase works fine with Amazon's SDK Tester (which provides a sandbox), but when I try it on the released game it fails. I don't have a Kindle Fire or such, but I install the game using the Amazon Store App onto my Android phone. Here is relevant logcat:

```
I/AmazonAppstore.BackoffRetryHandler(26295): Got a retry request
I/AmazonAppstore.BackoffRetryHandler(26295): Not retrying client error: 400
I/AmazonAppstore.BackoffRetryHandler(26295): Retrying request? false
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): Received a service error in response: status code=400, message=1 validation error detected: Value '[]' at 'vendorSkuList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length greater than or equal to 1]
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): com.amazon.iap.client.exception.ServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value '[]' at 'vendorSkuList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length greater than or equal to 1]
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.iap.client.interceptor.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor.after(IAPErrorTypeInterceptor.java:71)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.iap.client.util.Web.after(Web.java:295)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.iap.client.util.Web.execute(Web.java:317)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.iap.IAPClient.request(IAPClient.java:442)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.iap.IAPClient.getProductsByVendorSku(IAPClient.java:328)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.catalog.CatalogManagerImpl$GetProductsByVendorSku.getItems(CatalogManagerImpl.java:129)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.catalog.CatalogManagerImpl.getItems(CatalogManagerImpl.java:103)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.catalog.CatalogManagerImpl.getItems(CatalogManagerImpl.java:52)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.purchase.AbstractPurchaseFragment$PurchaseInitiateMetric.doInBackground(AbstractPurchaseFragment.java:598)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.purchase.AbstractPurchaseFragment$PurchaseInitiateMetric.doInBackground(AbstractPurchaseFragment.java:593)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor(26295): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): Error determining item type when creating detail page
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): com.amazon.mas.client.iap.catalog.CatalogRequestException: com.amazon.iap.client.exception.ServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value '[]' at 'vendorSkuList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length greater than or equal to 1]
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.catalog.CatalogManagerImpl.getItems(CatalogManagerImpl.java:105)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.catalog.CatalogManagerImpl.getItems(CatalogManagerImpl.java:52)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.purchase.AbstractPurchaseFragment$PurchaseInitiateMetric.doInBackground(AbstractPurchaseFragment.java:598)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.purchase.AbstractPurchaseFragment$PurchaseInitiateMetric.doInBackground(AbstractPurchaseFragment.java:593)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): Caused by: com.amazon.iap.client.exception.ServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value '[]' at 'vendorSkuList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length greater than or equal to 1]
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.iap.client.interceptor.IAPErrorTypeInterceptor.after(IAPErrorTypeInterceptor.java:71)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.iap.client.util.Web.after(Web.java:295)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.iap.client.util.Web.execute(Web.java:317)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.iap.IAPClient.request(IAPClient.java:442)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.iap.IAPClient.getProductsByVendorSku(IAPClient.java:328)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.catalog.CatalogManagerImpl$GetProductsByVendorSku.getItems(CatalogManagerImpl.java:129)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): at com.amazon.mas.client.iap.catalog.CatalogManagerImpl.getItems(CatalogManagerImpl.java:103)
E/AmazonAppstore.IAP/AbstractPurchaseFragment(26295): ... 8 more
W/BroadcastQueue( 831): Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.amazon.venezia.command.analytics.LifecycleEvent flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.amazon.venezia/com.amazon.mas.client.analytics.TailwindBroadcastReceiver requires com.amazon.mas.client.GLOBAL_BROADCAST-com.amazon.mShop.android due to sender com.amazon.mShop.android (uid 10016)
I/AmazonAppstore.BasicUserPreferences(26295): Reading from content://com.amazon.mas.client.settings/boolean/com.amazon.mas.client.framework.SettingsService.Collect3pAppUsage
```

It's coming from the guts of the Amazon IAPplugin parts from Unity. I call AmazonIAP.initiateItemDataRequest in the beginning of the game, with the list of the SKUs of my inventory. Seems like it returns fine. What else can I do?
Any help is appreciated.

A fellow Unity developer advised to hack Amazon IAP 2.0 into the IAP 1.0 plugin. But it's not that easy, I'd have to replace the encompassed jar, rewrite the bindings...

Comment: Also, I'm posting here because I didn't get any help whatsoever in Amazon developer forums.

Comment: Let me know if I should repost this to Unity section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh `in-app-purchasing-1.0.3.jar` in the guts of the Unity plugin supplied by Amazon with `in-app-purchasing-1.0.20.jar`. Besides that I added a call to `initiateGetUserIdRequest`, not sure how much that matters: `initiateItemDataRequest` worked before without that.
So one of these changes or both of them made the headache go away.
No I have 3 calls in the Unity game/app:

1. `AmazonIAP.initiateItemDataRequest (QueryInventory ()); // QueryInventory is my own function, I know my inventory right now, I don't build it dynamically.`
2. `AmazonIAP.initiateGetUserIdRequest (); // Still during IAP initialization`
3. `AmazonIAP.initiatePurchaseRequest(itemID); // itemId is the SKU string`

I utilize the `AmazonIAPEventListener.cs` supplied by the IAP plugin almost as it is, I just needed to wire in the increase of the game's virtual currency:

```
void purchaseSuccessfulEvent( AmazonReceipt receipt ) {
    AmazonIAP.Log("purchaseSuccessfulEvent: " + receipt );
    PlayerCredits.AddPlayerCredits (receipt.sku);
}
```

Hope this helps others!